# date range and event days count on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.3

which is for you the best way for store into a DB some event date range ? if you after need to check how many Event you have for every day in a month ?
example

```
1st event from 12/07 to 15/07
2th event from 14/07 to 17/07
3th event just at 15/07
```

if I check into DB with one query I expect that result:

```
12/07,(1 event) 
13/07,(1 event) 
14/07,(2 event) 
15/07,(3 event) 
16/07,(1 event) 
17/07,(1 event)
```

if I use the start_day and the end_day for store some Event maybe I've a small problem on that way:

if I use that 2 element (start_day & end_day) I select just how many Event between that date not how many event for each day, for example if you have 1 event and the duration is 3 days (from 11 to 14) and another event of 2 days (from 12 to 14), if I check how many event I've the 13 i don't have nothing because the date not appears but appears just if i check with SELECT * FROM event BETWEEN date_begin AND date_end

Comment: Question is unclear(_at least for me_)

Comment: You would use two Date or DateTime columns.

Comment: @max two date I don't need the time, but I need to count how many event I've every day.

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ which part isn't clear for you?

Comment: just show table definition and sample data

Comment: @wingᴇdpᴀnᴛʜᴇʀ I don't have a table or something like that, I want find the better way for implement that part, for now the problem is: how I can save an event and count how many room is occupied every day and how many event for each day... But if I save every event just with start_day end finish_day became hard count how many event I have in every single day because before I need to explode every rage of every event and after make a query for check every days or the select day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit simpler to do with post-processing in Ruby. Suppose you have the following `date_begin` and `date_end`:

```
date_begin = Date.new(2015, 7).beginning_of_month
date_end = Date.new(2015, 7).end_of_month
```

Then you can query the events in the specified range with

```
Event.where('start_day >= ? AND end_day <= ?', date_begin, date_end)
```

To obtain a count per day, you can post-process the results like this

```
Event.where('start_day >= ? AND end_day <= ?', date_begin, date_end)
  .flat_map{|event| (event.start_day..event.end_day).to_a }
  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|day, counts| counts[day] += 1 }
```

If you really want to do it in plain SQL, you can generate a sequence of days in the specified range and then join that on the events table.

```
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute <<-SQL
  SELECT day, count(events) FROM (
    SELECT day
    FROM generate_series('#{date_begin}'::date, '#{date_end}', '1 day')
    AS day
  ) days
  INNER JOIN events
  ON day BETWEEN start_day AND end_day
  GROUP BY day
SQL
```

If you want to turn that into a Hash that looks like the one from the first method, you can do this like so

```
results.map{|r| [r['day'].to_date, r['count'].to_i] }.to_h
```

Both methods will yield the following result:

```
{
  Sun, 12 Jul 2015=>1,
  Mon, 13 Jul 2015=>1,
  Tue, 14 Jul 2015=>2,
  Wed, 15 Jul 2015=>3,
  Thu, 16 Jul 2015=>1,
  Fri, 17 Jul 2015=>1
}
```